# Move vs copy performance in custom classes

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, c++14, move-semantics

How (if at all) does creating an instance of a class via move ctor improve performance, compared to the copy ctor, if the members of said class are mainly basic types like int etc. 
aren't those members just copied like in the copy ctor? So when does move provide better performance, when dealing with custom classes?

Comment: If all data members are basic types, I'd say there shouldn't be any change in terms of performance. They are just copied over to the new instance in both cases. Move constructors can be used when you have data stored on the dynamic storage and you don't want to copy them for it would be expensive, as an example.

Comment: @skypjack:  ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are right. It was late night here in Italy and I didn't have the mood to articulate a comment in a full answer. Sorry. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How (if at all) does creating an instance of a class via move ctor
>   improve performance, compared to the copy ctor, if the members of said
>   class are mainly basic types like int etc. aren't those members just
>   copied like in the copy ctor?

In the case where all the member variables are by-value/POD, there shouldn't be any difference at all.

> So when does move provide better performance, when dealing with
>   custom classes?

The move constructor provides an advantage only in the case where the newly-constructed object can "steal" resources from the already-existing object.

For example, imagine that you have a temporary `std::string` that contains the entire contents of the novel 'War and Peace' -- all 1440 pages of it.

In the classic copy-constructor case, if you wanted to assign that temporary string to a non-temporary `std::string` (e.g. a member-variable or global-variable or whatever), the program would have to perform the following steps:

- Free any previous buffer that the destination `std::string` might have been holding
- Allocate a new buffer that is (1440*chars_per_page) bytes long for the destination `std::string` to hold
- Copy all 1440 pages of data from the temporary `std::string`'s buffer to the destination `std::string`'s buffer
- Delete the temporary string's buffer (when the temporary string goes out of scope)

As you can see, this would be inefficient, as we copied a ton of data even though we never actually needed a second copy of the data.  Since we have a move constructor implemented for `std::string`, however, C++11 programs can be smarter and just do this:

- Free any previous buffer that the destination `std::string` might have been holding
- Transfer the giant buffer from the temporary `std::string` to the destination `std::string` (note that all we do is copy the pointer-to-the-buffer value of the source string to the destination string; in particular we *don't* need to copy, or even read, any of the actual 1440-pages of data!)
- Set the temporary string's pointer-to-the-buffer value to NULL (so it won't try to free it or use it later on)

... and that's it; instead of having to allocate a second big buffer and then copy gobs of data, we were able to achieve the desired end-state simply by swizzling a couple of pointer values.  That's a big performance win, and we can get away with doing that because we know that the temporary-string is about to be deleted anyway, so there's no harm in "stealing" the internal data it was holding.

I don't know if `std::string` counts as a 'custom class' exactly, but you can use the same technique in your own classes any time you have a class that dynamically allocates internal state.

Answer (score 1):

> How (if at all) does creating an instance of a class via move ctor improve performance, compared to the copy ctor, if the members of said class are mainly basic types like int etc.

It doesn't.

> Aren't those members just copied like in the copy ctor?

Yes.

> So when does move provide better performance, when dealing with custom classes?

When you have "indirect" resources, like data referred to by pointers so you can just "swap" the pointers and avoid even touching the stuff they point to. (That's like unhooking a caravan from your car, and re-hooking it onto a different car.) That's it.

There's no benefit in making a class movable if it only consists of data that must be copied anyway. (That's like trying to "move" the contents of a caravan to another caravan: you have no choice but to actually go in, pick everything up and transfer it by hand.)

Answer (score 0):

> How (if at all) does creating an instance of a class via move ctor improve performance  compared to the copy ctor

You're misunderstanding. Typically, you're not making a choice about whether an object is constructed with the move ctor or the copy ctor - it's implicit in the context of its definition. So it's not like there's much of an alternative. Of course, if a move ctor is not available then copy construction is a fallback. Still, don't think about it as a choice.

> if the members of said class are mainly basic types like int etc. aren't those members just copied like in the copy ctor?

They might not be copied at all, i.e. the compiler might completely elide the construction of an object and just use the one you're passing. But if construction actually happens, then yes, `int`s and such will just be copied (assuming the default move ctor).

> So when does move provide better performance, when dealing with custom classes?

Again, you're thinking about it wrong. Move constructor is for moving, copy constructor is for copying. For some classes the move constructor may be faster (e.g. if you can switch allocated buffers and such); for some it isn't.

Further reading: [Reasonable presentation on these two kinds of ctors](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/move-constructor/) on [Andrzej's C++ blog](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/).

Comment: I didn't follow all of this but there seems to be at least one misconception in your answer; elision doesn't require move semantics, at all. Copy elision has existed for a long time. Besides that I'm not really sure that you answered the question, nor provided any evidence to back up your repeated claim that the OP doesn't understand: as far as I can tell, they understand just fine.